# createOrUpdateInRealm:withObject: unexpectedly resets to many relationship when updated with the same object

Tags: objective-c, realm

It seems like to many relationships are reset when you update a realm object with itself.  The following code will result in the persons dogs becoming orphaned.

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm transactionWithBlock:^{
    self.person.name = @"Fred";
    NSLog(@"dogs before: %d", self.person.dogs.count);
    self.person = [Person createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withObject:self.person];
    NSLog(@"dogs after: %d", self.person.dogs.count);
}];
```

*Console Output*

```
dogs before: 1
dogs after: 0
```

I used create or update as at this point I don't know whether I have a new object or a previously persisted object.

I have functioning alternative but **I am curious as to why this doesn't work?**  My best guess was it is something to do with key value coding used in mapping the data to the object returning some "unexpected" value.

**Is there any appropriate way to avoid this problem or should I just stick with my alternative approach?**

*Functioning alternative*

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm transactionWithBlock:^{
    if (![self.person realm]) {
        [realm addObject:self.person];
    }

    self.person.name = @"Fred";
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Realm, calling a setter for an object's properties is sufficient to update that object (as long as you are inside a write transaction).

Calling `createOrUpdateInRealm` with a persisted `RLMObject` subclass will create a *duplicate* of that object in the database, and in fact will [throw an exception in the future](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1409).

In short, you should not be calling `createOrUpdateInRealm` in this situation, merely setting the person's `name` property inside a write transaction.

Comment: It doesn't throw any exceptions and works fine apart from the problem I described.  I take your point about setting the name being sufficient _provided that your object is already in a realm_.  The main question I wished clarification for was why when you create or update with the same object, does it lose its relationships.  It just doesn't seem to be desirable behaviour.

Comment: @nacross we just released an [update](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0903-release-notes-2015-01-27) this morning that should fix things. Please update to 0.90.3 and let me know if things are working for you!